# Getting error message "li: 'key' is not a prop"

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with React (version 15.4.2), and I'm populating a `<ul>` dynamically with query results from my database. I thought that I had set up the 'key' property on the `<li>`s correctly, but evidently I have not - when the list renders, I get the error:

> Warning: li: 'key' is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in 'undefined' being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.

Here's the code for my list:

```
function UserList(props) {
    return(
        <ul className="UserList">
            {
                props.user_list.map((user) => (
                    <li className="UserListItem" key={user.id}>
                        <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.first_name} {user.last_name}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

I took a look at [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), and it seems to me like this should be correct. If anyone could clarify my mistake, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What line is that warning generated for, and can you show what's on that line? (and the lines around it obviously).

Comment: are you calling `props.key` anywhere?

Comment: To the first comment, I'm not entirely sure - this warning is generated by `warning.js`, and it is the only line logged to my console.  To the second comment, no, I haven't called `props.key` anywhere - the only other code in this component are the `import`s and the `export default`. Where would I call that?

Comment: i got the same warning message, but i think that is kind a bug because if you open the page in incognito mode don't throw any warning message.

Comment: I realize that the message came from the [react extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) of google chrome, so maybe is not a problem of react.

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code. I mocked up a jsbin with react 15.4.2 and it doesn't show any errors. http://jsbin.com/gasanulute/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @BrandonRoberts thank you so much for taking the time to put that together.

Comment: @Maxtermax I think you are on to something...

Answer (score 61):

Somewhere else in the code you're trying to access props.key

Basically, "key" props are not passed to a child component.

React [docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html) say: "special props (ref and key) are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component.".

Answer (score 9):

You could wrap the li in a React fragment, e.g.

```js
{props.user_list.map((user, index) => (
         <React.Fragment key={index}>
           <li className="UserListItem" >
             <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.first_name} {user.last_name}</Link>
           </li>
         </React.Fragment>
    ))
}
```

Comment: This is crazy, even doing this I get ```Warning: Symbol(react.fragment): `key` is not a prop.```. I really don't understand the problem

Comment: using indexes as keys is a bad pattern. 
See this recommendation from the react docs:
"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys."
https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is, try to see what happens if you do `props.user_list.map((user, index)` and for `key`, give it `index` instead of `user.id`.

If this process makes the warning go away, you can be reasonably sure you have a duplicate `id` for the `user`. In this case, I would suggest you turn your attention to the backend that produces the list of users. How is `id` created? It may be worth taking a look at [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to make sure you uniquely identify your users.

If this test persist with the error, I would recommend trying to upgrade the react version, but I highly doubt this will be the case.

Comment: using indexes as keys is a bad pattern. See this recommendation from the react docs: "We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys." robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Maybe user.id is duplicated, pls check again

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this warning for a while so I figured out that it was caused by simple
console.log(mapped_variable) and then returning it in component. When I commented console.log, warning disappeared.

In your case, check if UserList(props) is not console logged somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PropTypes to validate props, like this:

```
Progress.propTypes = {
    labels: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    tab: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    key: PropTypes.number.isRequired. <!--- this line will trigger the error--->
}
```

Remove 'key' from PropTypes checking to remove this error.

Comment: "key" is never a valid prop, see https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html