# Material UI ListItem not letting me set a unique key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for React and am getting the following error when trying to pass a key prop to a ListItem:

> Warning: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned.If you need to
>   access the same value within the child component, you should pass it
>   as a different prop.

```
<ListItem
      primaryText={video.snippet.title}
      leftAvatar={<Avatar src={imageUrl} />}
      key={key}
    />
```

Am I missing something or is this likely to be a bug in the Material UI library?

Comment: What version of react/react-devtools are you using?

Comment: Could you add the surrounding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to say the issue was that I was trying to pass the key to the component via a prop called 'key' which of course isn't possible in React!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using React dev tools and the warning is from this browser extension. You can find similar problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261505/react-li-key-is-not-a-prop-error) and github issue (it's solved) [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/518).

Anyway, your code is fine.