# why do I get "`key` is not a prop." in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I have the code below, with `bookList_object` being a bunch of JSON objects I fetched from backend.

```
   _renderBookList = () => {
        const books = this.state.bookList_object.map((this_book, index) => {
        return <BookList 
          body={this_book.body}
          created_at={this_book.created_at}
          key = {index}
        />
    })
```

Now, I've learned that there has to be `key` when having multiple children. So I've used `index` parameter to assign each id to the `key` prop. But then I get this error: 
"BookList: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop."
What have I done wrong? 
Also, I already have `id` field in each of my object. Is there a way to use `id` instead of `key`?

Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error message "li: 'key' is not a prop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261505/getting-error-message-li-key-is-not-a-prop)

Comment: Yes, if you have a unique id, you can : `key={this_book.id}`

Comment: @AjeetShah Not really :( I tried it and checked in my console, and what I got is ```key: (...)```. So I clicked it, and got the same error in the console.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a sandbox with minimal code?

Comment: So firstly this looks wrong. `_renderBookList` is not returning anything. All you do is declare the variable `books`, which is the list. Forget the variable and just `return this.state.bookList....` directly. I suspect the error is within the `BookList` component itself, since the rest of it looks right (assuming `bookList_object` is actually an array). However, it's strange that you map over your array and then don't use the `this_book` item at all.

Comment: Try to wrap <BookList /> in a div and then give that div a key attribute with the index. Had similar issue once and it worked in my case.

Comment: this is more than likely because you are trying to access `props.key` within the body of a component or in  proptype checking

Comment: `key` shouldn't be an index in most cases btw.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this `Warning`. It happened because I tried to assign a key to some elements in two different parts of the code. The warning pops up when the `key` prop is accessed a second time.

Find out where else the component is being assigned a key. Then choose only one place to assign a key.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it should be a problem w react

Answer (score 0):

Official docs say (emphasis mine):

> Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however, there are two special props (ref and key) which are used by React, and are thus **not forwarded to the component**.

So doing something like this would generate the warning:

```
export default function BookList ({body, created_at, key /* <= will be undefined */}) => {
    // Warning appears even if `key` isn't used here
}
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
export default function BookList ({body, created_at}) => {
    // If you need `key` for something add a new property
}
```