# Warning: `key` is not a prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a component "List of notes", which contains a child component "Note". The "Note" also contains a child component, the "Note Block". It looks like this:

**ListOfNotes**

```
<section className='list-of-notes'>
    {notes?.map((note) => (
        <Note
            key={note.note_id}
            note_id={note.note_id}
            title={note.title}
            blocks={note.blocks}
            published={note.published}
            updated={note.updated}
        />
    ))}
</section>
```

**Note**

```
    const Note = (note: TNote) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const openNoteEditor = () => {
        document.body.style.paddingRight = `${window.innerWidth - document.body.offsetWidth}px`;
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';

        dispatch(showNotePopup(true));
        dispatch(setCurrentNote(note));
    };

    return (
        <div className='note' onClick={openNoteEditor}>
            <h3 className='note__title'>{note.title}</h3>

            {note.blocks?.map((block) => (
                <NoteBlock key={block.id} id={block.id} type={block.type} data={block.data} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**NoteBlock**

```
const NoteBlock = (block: TBlock) => {
    if (block.type === 'subtitle') {
        return (
            <ReactTextareaAutosize
                className='note__block note__block-subtitle'
                value={block.data.text}
                readOnly
            />
        );
    }
    if (block.type === 'paragraph') {
        return (
            <ReactTextareaAutosize
                className='note__block note__block-paragraph'
                value={block.data.text}
                readOnly
            />
        );
    }
    if (block.type === 'code') {
        return (
            <ReactTextareaAutosize
                className='note__block note__block-code'
                value={block.data.text}
                readOnly
            />
        );
    }
    return <div>Данных нет</div>;
};
```

**Types**

```
export type TNote = {
    note_id: number;
    title: string;
    updated: string;
    published: boolean;
    blocks: TBlock[];
};

export type TBlock = {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    data: {
        text: string;
    };
};
```

**Everything works for me but in the console I get a warning:**

*Warning: Note: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. (https://reactjs.org/link/special-props)*

I can't figure out what exactly the React doesn't like about this chain. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the definition of `Note`? You only showed the HTML, not the actual component definition. I believe your problem is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261505/getting-error-message-li-key-is-not-a-prop . So inside your `Note` component you are probably trying to access the `key` prop but that isn't forwarded by React

Comment: I added a definition of the Note. When I click on a note, I transfer the data to a state. Then another component will open to edit the current note. I don't get direct access to the key property. The warning occurs when I edit the current note in the editing component.

Comment: What does `setCurrentNote` do? Maybe that function is trying to access `key`

Comment: state.currentNote = action.payload; I just looked at the payload in the console. I see key:undefined. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/h83S-WAh2xXnQQ I don't understand what's going on)

Comment: key is probably defined in TNote or TBlock, leading to the warning that you have. To fix,  remove key from these.

Comment: The problem is in the key that I pass to the List Of Notes. If I delete it, the warning disappears, but there is a warning about the absence of the key.  The key property is not used anywhere for me

Comment: Create a dummy component of `<Note>`, like just a component returning `null` but which still receives the same props as your real component. Do you still have the error?

Comment: Yes, the warning persists.

Comment: Uh... that's weird. Can you reproduce the problem on a CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem like this: `dispatch(setCurrentNote({ ...note }));`

Do not send directly a "props" object to redux.

Comment: You should accept your answer as it might help other people in the future. =)